# Wireless Network not Showing Up in Network List

Tags: wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with GNOME default theme. After installation, I configured wifi and it was working perfectly fine. But suddenly after couple of days its not connecting to my network. The biggest surprise is that the wifi menu is showing all the networks available except mine.

Laptop : Acer Aspire 5750Z

Comment: Can you access your Wifi with other devices?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 also as dual boot. Wifi is working fine in Windows. I was slowly loving Uduntu these days, but this problem is really making me to switch back to windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Wifi menu select 'Connect to Hidden Network' and type in your network SSID.

Comment: I tried that too. My wifi network was showing as the last item in Network window showing status as "Out of Range". When I tried connecting as "Connect to Hidden Network", its shows like connecting.. but after couple of seconds no change and still appearing as Out of Range.

Comment: Its not showing any errors. If its showing errors, at least I can figure out something problem with connection or some driver problem. I'm still wondering how my wifi network alone showing as "Out of Range" ? while all other available networks nearby are detecting.

Comment: Please check the below link, I have attached the screenshot of my Network window :  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u437gh&s=5

Comment: Hmm Not sure if rebooting your router will help, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Also please check another screen shot on below link showing the wifi menu list :(  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=122n888&s=5

Comment: Hey Dan, I rebooted router.. its working fine. Wifi conneted! thanks a lot:) so happy. I'm back to Ubuntu now :) thanks again..

Comment: Its amazing the things a reboot can fix.